# Out-of-memory join of two csv's with varying number of columns

Tags: python, csv, command-line, concatenation

I have a historic csv that needs to be updated daily (concatenated) with a freshly pulled csv. The issue is that the new csv may have different number of columns from the historic one. If each of them was light, I could just read in both and concatenate with `pandas`. If the number of columns was the same, I could use `cat` and do a command-line call. Unfortunately, neither is true.

So, I am wondering if there is a way to do out-of-memory concatenation/join with pandas for something like above, or using one of the command line tools.

Thanks!

Comment: concatenate with `awk`? Not sure what you mean by "light" or what is the specific issue with different columns.

Comment: I'm confused... are you processing the new stuff to match the format of the old? If so, can't you just append to the file after processing?

Comment: I just need to append csv_a to csv_b. They have different number of columns; some matching, some don’t. That’s it. The problem is that both can be large sizes (_a for sure), so I don’t want to be doing that in-memory.

Comment: @Anarcho-Chossid - _"they have different number of columns"_ How do you plan to deal with that? Why do you need to read the first csv? Can you explain why simply processing the new csv to make it match the old format doesn't work?

Comment: I mean something like this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/_images/merging_concat_axis1.png Except, in that example, you have repeating rows between two dataframes (numbers 2 and 3), and in my example, you wouldn’t.

Comment: "Can you explain why simply processing the new csv to make it match the old format doesn't work?” Because the new csv has columns which the old one doesn’t. How would I “process” that? I need those data to be in the new update (with NAs for the rows from the old dataset).

Comment: @Anarcho-Chossid - So, you want to update existing rows in the old csv? Why didn't you just say so? As for _How would I "process that"?_ I have no idea. I'm not sitting in your room looking over your shoulder. I'm walking away from this one.